# android intentを用いて画面遷移するとき同じActivityが開いてしまう

Tags: android, java, android-intent

androidでカウンターアプリを作りたいのですが、うまくいきません。
やりたいことは、Mainactivity(Countermain)で「Config」ボタンがおされた時にSubactivity(Newcounter)に移動するということです。(戻る処理はまだ実装していません)
これを実行したところ、intentを使った部分がうまく働いていないことが分かりました。具体的には、Configを押すとCounterconfigが開く予定なのにCountermainが開いてしまいます。Manifestファイルにも登録はしたはずなのですが...
同じ症状になったことがある方や、原因がわかる方ご回答お願いします。
伝わらなかったことや足りないことがあれば答えます。
Androidバージョンは4.X(API19)
eclipseは4.4(たぶん)です
以下ソース
　　　　
    **Countermain.java**

```
package countermain.countermain;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class Countermain extends Activity implements OnClickListener{   private int mCount;//←カウンターの数字を入れておく変数
   @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.countermain);//c_mainは
    Button btn = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button12);//←button12はConfigキー
    btn.setOnClickListener(this);
}

   @Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}

   //カウンター部分の処理

   public void plus(View view) {
     mCount++;
     updateCountView();
}

   public void minus(View view) {
    mCount--;
    updateCountView();
}

   public void clear(View view) {
    mCount = 0;
    updateCountView();
}
   public void btnst1(View view) {
    mCount = 0;
    updateCountView();
}
   public void btnst2(View view) {
    mCount = 0;
    updateCountView();
}
   public void btnst3(View view) {
    mCount = 0;
    updateCountView();
}
   public void btnst4(View view) {
    mCount = 0;
    updateCountView();
}
   public void btnst5(View view) {
    mCount = 0;
    updateCountView();
}
   public void btnst6(View view) {
    mCount = 0;
    updateCountView();
}
   public void btnst7(View view) {
    mCount = 0;
    updateCountView();
}
   public void btnst8(View view) {
    mCount = 0;
    updateCountView();
}

   public void onClick(View v) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(this,Newcounter.class);//←おかしい部分？    
    startActivity(intent);
}
    private void updateCountView() {
    TextView countView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);
    countView.setText(String.valueOf(mCount));
    }
```

**countermain.xml**
     
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
        android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
        android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
        android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
        tools:context="countermain.countermain.Countermain" >

```
<Button
    android:id="@+id/button3"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/button2"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/button2"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_marginRight="47dp"
    android:onClick="clear"
    android:text="clear" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/button1"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/button1"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:onClick="minus"
    android:text="-1" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_marginTop="42dp"
    android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/button2"
    android:onClick="plus"
    android:text="+1" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button4"
    style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_below="@+id/button1"
    android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="36dp"
    android:onClick="btnst1"
    android:text="Button" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button5"
    style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/button4"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/button4"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/button4"
    android:onClick="btnst2"
    android:text="Button" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button6"
    style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/button5"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/button5"
    android:onClick="btnst3"
    android:text="Button" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button7"
    style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/button6"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/button6"
    android:onClick="btnst4"      
    android:text="Button" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button8"
    style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignRight="@+id/button4"
    android:layout_below="@+id/button4"
    android:onClick="btnst5"
    android:text="Button" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button9"
    style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/button8"
    android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/button6"
    android:onClick="btnst6"
    android:text="Button" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button10"
    style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/button5"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/button5"
    android:onClick="btnst7"
    android:text="Button" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button11"
    style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/button7"
    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/button10"
    android:onClick="btnst8"
    android:text="Button" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button12"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:text="config" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/button2"
    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/button12"
    android:layout_marginTop="21dp"
    android:text="0"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
    android:textSize="90sp" />
```

**CountermainのManifest**
    

    package="countermain.countermain"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

```
<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="19"
    android:targetSdkVersion="19" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >  

     <activity
        android:name="Countermain"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
       android:name="Newcounter"
       android:label="@string/app_name"
        > 
    </activity>



</application>
```

**Newcounter.java**

```
package countermain.countermain;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import countermain.countermain.R;

public class Newcounter extends Activity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.countermain);
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```

}

**newcounter.xml**

    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="config.config.Counterconfig" >

```
<EditText
    android:id="@+id/EditText02"
    android:layout_width="70dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/EditText01"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/EditText01"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/EditText01"
    android:ems="10"
    android:inputType="number" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/EditText01"
    android:layout_width="70dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/editText1"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/editText1"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/editText1"
    android:ems="10"
    android:inputType="number" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/EditText03"
    android:layout_width="70dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/EditText02"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/EditText02"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/EditText02"
    android:ems="10"
    android:inputType="number" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/TextView01"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignRight="@+id/EditText02"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:text="ボタン3" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/TextView02"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/EditText02"
    android:text="ボタン2" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/TextView03"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignRight="@+id/EditText03"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:text="ボタン4" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/TextView07"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignRight="@+id/EditText03"
    android:layout_below="@+id/EditText03"
    android:layout_marginTop="25dp"
    android:text="ボタン8" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/TextView06"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/TextView07"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/TextView07"
    android:layout_alignRight="@+id/EditText01"
    android:text="ボタン6" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/TextView05"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/TextView07"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/TextView07"
    android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/EditText03"
    android:text="ボタン7" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/TextView04"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/TextView06"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/TextView06"
    android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/EditText01"
    android:text="ボタン5" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/EditText06"
    android:layout_width="70dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/TextView04"
    android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/EditText01"
    android:ems="10"
    android:inputType="number" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/EditText07"
    android:layout_width="70dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/EditText06"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/EditText06"
    android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/EditText02"
    android:ems="10"
    android:inputType="number" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/EditText04"
    android:layout_width="70dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/EditText07"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/EditText07"
    android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/EditText03"
    android:ems="10"
    android:inputType="number" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/EditText05"
    android:layout_width="70dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/EditText04"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/EditText04"
    android:layout_alignRight="@+id/TextView07"
    android:ems="10"
    android:inputType="number" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_above="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginBottom="47dp"
    android:text="ボタンを一回押すごとに     増える数の設定"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/TextView02"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/TextView02"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textView2"
    android:layout_marginLeft="22dp"
    android:text="ボタン１" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/editText1"
    android:layout_width="70dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignRight="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_below="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
    android:ems="10"
    android:inputType="number" />
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

NewCounter.javaのビュー設定がcountermain.xmlとなっているためでは？

具体的に言うとNewcounter.javaのonCreate()中の

setContentView(R.layout.countermain);
が
setContentView(R.layout.newcounter);
となっていないためではないでしょうか．

Comment: kysiskiさんの言うとおりにしたら解決しました！
ありがとうございます！これで進められます！
本当にありがとうございました。